# Hola, buenos dias. Alguien se ha encontrado con el error que Expo se detiene en la depuración sin lanzar ningun error, que puedo hacer?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, vscode, expo

Expo se detiene o se bloquea sin lanzar error al pasar contenido de un carousel a un screen, o sea pasa el contenido y luego de 2 o tres segundos expo sale de la aplicion sin lanzar error.

No tengo errores ni sugerencias en el código, por eso no se probar